# Exception is thrown by SOS

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

I'm just getting started with windbg/sos and I created a simple console application for testing (that throws an unhandled exception). It seems like after I load sos I will get an exception on the very next call.

For example:

```
ntsd consoleapplication1.exe
.symfix
.reload
g
.loadby sos clr
```

if I call:

```
!threads
"c0000005 Exception in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.threads
      PC: 592b7713  VA: 00000000  R/W: 0  Parameter: 00000000"
```

if I call:

```
!ClrStack
c0000005 Exception in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.ClrStack
      PC: 592b7713  VA: 00000000  R/W: 0  Parameter: 00000000
```

Every call after my 1st call will work (it's only the first call that fails after loading SOS).

I tried this [recommendation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1afc37dd-2e47-4099-8893-cdbe14f6861c/exception-in-cwindowsmicrosoftnetframeworkv4030319sosthreads-debugger-extension?forum=clr) and recompiled my code with native code debugging enabled but it did not make a difference.

Version of windbg: 6.3.9600.16384 X86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a problem of WinDbg. I tried it with a .NET 4.0 console application, x86 target. I did not check the checkmark for *Enable native code debugging*, since I never did that before.

I can reproduce your problem in WinDbg (NTSD) 6.**3.9600**.16384 x86 with both debug build and release build.

For me it works with WinDbg (NTSD) 6.**2.9200**.16384 x86 with both debug build and release build.

Since I often have the problem of duplicate output in 6.3 anyway, I am still using version 6.2 as my default WinDbg version.

Comment: thanks i guess it wasn't only on my machine :P. Apparently its a bug in WinDbg